# Obtaining tab title/text using process ID

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I don't want to use `SetForegroundWindow()`, sending keyboard keys or similar techniques, because that can cause issues (unexpected behaviour) in my software.
I have tried to find the title using Cheat Engine program (but haven't found anything useful as Google Chrome seems to work "upside-down").

So I went step ahead, using Process Hacker program I have realized that there is a parent (chrome.exe) process with a valid window handle to the current active tab and all other chrome processes are children of it a.k.a. background processes (with invalid window handle).
By browsing deeper into windows of chrome.exe (parent process), I have found the class name of the window handle being "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" and current active tab's title/text.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jFsh.png) a picture of Google Chrome's Task Manager.

I'm looking for a function in C# or C or C++ that will take an integer (process ID) and return a string (tab title/text).

```
static string GetChromeTabTitle(uint processId)
{
    // Assuming I call this function with valid process identifier (PID).
    // What do I do next, here??
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do by getting Chrome tab's text?

Comment: Another approach to consider: given a process, get hold of the DOM object and retrieve the `title` tag.

Comment: @JamesThorpe That actually sounds like a good idea. But I have no clue where and how to start..

Comment: Nor do I - just wanted to highlight it as a potential alternative while you're researching :)

Comment: There are useful informations on chrome://memory-internals/ and chrome://memory-redirect/ pages (links are only viewable from Google Chrome web-browser). But, there is no such API (as far as I know - as of 14th August 2015) which could "extract/access to" these informations DIRECTLY from 3rd party application/code. Sad :-(

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is by using the [System.Windows.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx) library. It allows interacting with an application (primarily for accessibility purposes), but you can use it for other purposes like getting Chrome tabs.

Note that this will *only* work when the Chrome windows is not minimized.

The process is not exactly simple, if you want you can look how I did it in my own project, though it's not something you can just copy it paste, you'll find what you need in the `ChromeTabsFinder`: https://github.com/christianrondeau/GoToWindow/blob/master/GoToWindow.Plugins.ExpandBrowsersTabs/Chrome/ChromeTabsFinder.cs

Here's the code (you'll need the automation librairies):

```
public IEnumerable<ITab> GetTabsOfWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
  var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest();
  cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
  cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty);
  cacheRequest.Add(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
  cacheRequest.Add(SelectionItemPattern.SelectionContainerProperty);
  cacheRequest.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element;

  AutomationElement tabBarElement;

  using (cacheRequest.Activate())
  {
    var chromeWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

    var mainElement = chromeWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Google Chrome"));

    if (mainElement == null)
      yield break;

    tabBarElement = mainElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "tab"));
  }

  if(tabBarElement == null)
    yield break;

  var tabElements = tabBarElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "tab item"));

  for (var tabIndex = 0; tabIndex < tabElements.Count; tabIndex++)
  {
    yield return "Tab: " + tabElements[tabIndex].Current.Name + ", Index: " + tabIndex + 1;
  }
}
```